# How to load html modules via ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Depending upon a path that a user enters my site through I want to load the correct module?

Is this as simple as storing the HTML in a file called `some_file.htm` then ajaxing that file to the client than appending it to the DOM?

I'm wondering if it is that easy or if there are some caveats I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it can be really that easy - if you use a framework (like jQuery).

However be aware of escaping and code validity!

Comment: I'm not using a framework, what do I need to escape, can I just append to the .innerHTML property of the containing div?

Comment: I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: Yes you can just append the innerHTML property - http://jsfiddle.net/f4Sp9/ shows any html string can be appended, you dont need to escape anything if some_file.html is a static file containing some html structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example:

JavaScript:

```
<script defer="true">
    (function(){

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.addEventListener("load", function(resp){
            document.querySelector('div.container').innerHTML = resp.target.responseText;
        }, false);

        xhr.open("get", "some_file.htm", true);
        xhr.send();
    }());
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I think OP wasnt asking how to do it but whether its possible :) However nice example :)

Comment: I know it is possible and how to do it, I was asking if there are any caveats?  Particularly, the escaping.

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com if your content is static and you know what it contains then you need NO escaping - you need the pure code :)